# Asynchronous loading of URL in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, url

My App loads a URL to a `.txt` file on my web server. I’m getting this warning:

> Synchronous URL loading of https://(path to my text file)/nowplaying.txt should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.

I can't find any examples to modify my code.  Here’s what I’m using now that generates the error.

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *stringURL = @"https://(path to my text file)/nowplaying.txt";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[urlData bytes]];
    _lblNowPlaying.text = dataString;
}
```

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL` should only be used to fetch data from a local file. You will need to use something like [`NSURLSessionDataTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondatatask)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `NSURLSession`:

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *stringURL = @"https://(path to my text file)/nowplaying.txt";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (data) {
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.lblNowPlaying.text = string;
            });
        }
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

Note, `NSURLSession` runs its completion handler on a background serial queue, so you have to dispatch the update of the label to the main queue.

---

It is probably prudent to add some error checking, to check for `NSError` object and to check the status code returned by the web server:

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *stringURL = @"https://(path to my text file)/nowplaying.txt";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    if (!url) {
        NSLog(@"%s URL error: %@", __FUNCTION__, stringURL);
        return;
    }

    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%s error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
            return;
        }

        if (![response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSLog(@"%s response: %@", __FUNCTION__, response);
            return;
        }

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

        if (httpResponse.statusCode < 200 || httpResponse.statusCode >= 300) {
            NSLog(@"%s statusCode %ld; response: %@", __FUNCTION__, httpResponse.statusCode, response);
            return;
        }

        if (data) {
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.lblNowPlaying.text = string;
            });
        }
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```